# Map CSV Headers to SQL columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, csv

I am parsing CSV files and creating a list of objects that i will need to import them in a SQL DB. The csv file has different header names that i can map them for each column of a specific table.

LINQ fails as the names do not match.

I did try every possible tutorial and side way but cannot map the csv headers to a specific column of the db.

```cs
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
{
    List<CSVObject> ListCSVObject = new List<CSVObject>();
    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader);
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        CSVObject objectRow = csv.GetRecord<CSVObject>();
        double time = Convert.ToDouble(objectRow.Timestamp);
        DateTime dateTimeUTC = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(time);
        objectRow.DateTimeUTC = dateTimeUTC;
        ListCSVObject.Add(objectRow);
    }

    LINQToSQLDataContext db = new LINQToSQLDataContext(connectString);
    foreach(CSVObject obj in ListCSVObject)
    {
        db.dbtoinsert.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice: don't build your own CSV-file reader; use the Nuget package CsvHelper instead

CsvHelper can take any structured CSV file, with any kind of separator, and with or without a header line.

If your CSV has a header line, you can tell CSV helper that the column that is labeled "Family Name" should be put in the property "LastName" of your class.

Even if you don't have a header line in your CSV file, you can say that column 7 should be mapped to "LastName" and column 9 should be mapped to "BirthDay"

Visit [the documentation page](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) for easy examples

Answer (score 0):

You can do object initialization before inserting it to your database.

something like this.

`db.dbtoinsert.InsertOnSubmit(new YourTable { Col1 = obj.CSVCol1, ... });`